# My Object has no method?

Tags: jquery, oop, console.log

I'm having difficulty understanding why this code isn't working. From what I can tell my syntax is correct but the console.log complains that my person object doesn't have a method setFirstName. Here's what I've got so far:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="firstName">
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#firstName").on("change", getFirstName);

    var person = new Person();

    function Person() {
        this.firstName = "";
    }

    Person.prototype = {
        setFirstName: function(name) {
            this.firstName = name;
            console.log("My first name is: " + person.firstName);
        }
    }

    function getFirstName() {
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
    }
});
```

The console log displays this error and points to the "person.setFirstName(firstName)" line of code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Person> has no method 'setFirstName'
```

It's puzzling to me that it recognizes the Person object exists but then doesn't see the method setFirstName. What have I done wrong? Help me master coders, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current code assigns the object literal to the prototype of `Person`.  Instead, assign the function to the `setFirstName` property of `Person.prototype`:

```
Person.prototype.setFirstName = function(name) {
        this.firstName = name;
        console.log("My first name is: " + this.firstName);
}
```

## Explanation

To understand the error, we must first understand how `prototype`s work in Javascript.  When an instance of an object is created using a function constructor the instance's prototype is assigned the prototype of the constructor function.

```
function MyObject(){}
var myObj = new MyObject();
console.log(myObj.__proto__ == MyObject.prototype); //logs true
```

In the provided code, an instance of `Person` is created using the `Person` constructor function.  This causes `person` to be assigned the prototype of `Person`.

```
var person = new Person();
function Person() {
    this.firstName = "";
}
console.log(person.__proto__); //logs Person{}
```

Then the object literal containing the `setFirstName` function is assigned to the prototype of `Person`.

```
Person.prototype = {
    setFirstName: function(name) {
        this.firstName = name;
        console.log("My first name is: " + person.firstName);
    }
}
```

At this point the `Person` prototype is assigned to the object literal with the function, however the instance `person` was created before the object literal was assigned to `Person`'s prototype.  The instance `person`'s prototype does not refer to the object literal that was assigned to `Person.prototype` after its instantiation.

```
console.log(person.__proto__ == Person.prototype); //logs false
```

While not recommended, we could have resolved or avoided this issue by creating the `person` instance after the new prototype was assigned, such as:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#firstName").on("change", getFirstName);

    function Person() {
        this.firstName = "";
    }

    Person.prototype = {
        setFirstName: function(name) {
            this.firstName = name;
            console.log("My first name is: " + person.firstName);
        }
    }

    var person = new Person();
    function getFirstName() {
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
    }
});
```

It is much better to assign the method to a property of `Person.prototype` so that we do not create temporial coupling that dictates when an instance of `Person` can be created.

This [article](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/) does an excellent job of explaining `prototype` and would be worth the read.

Comment: Isn't my way just shorthand for this?

Comment: Nope, you are replacing the prototype with the object literal you create.

Comment: Fixed my typo. Thanks for catching it. Changed it to your suggestion and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @Frijolie I felt like I owed you a better explanation.  Please see the updated post.